# How to remove duplicate code and make clean code swift?

Tags: swift, duplicates

I have class and methods in this class.

There are duplicate lines in 2 methods but different return value.

How can I remove duplicate this lines and make it more cleaner.

duplicate lines are :

```
if let text = searchedText {
    if !text.isEmpty {
        let searchedFruits = fruits.filter { code }
             return 
    }
}
```

and class.

```
class FruitModel{
        var fruits: [Fruit]
        var searchedText: String?
        
        init() {
            //initialize
        }
        
        func getFruit() -> Int {
            if let text = searchedText {
                if !text.isEmpty {
                    let searchedFruits = fruits.filter { code }
                    return searchedFruits.count
                }
            }
            return fruits.count
        }
        
        func getFruitByIndex(_ at: Int) -> Fruit {
            if let text = searchedText {
                if !text.isEmpty {
                    let searchedFruits = fruits.filter { code }
                    return searchedFruits[at]
                }
            }
            return fruits[at]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Factor out to a common function. I don't see the difficulty.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson There is some filtering code using text

Comment: `sort -u myFile.swift`

Comment: How can you ever get `getFruitByIndex` to work? You don't know the result of the search yet you are accessing a specific index of the result?

Comment: This doesn’t even compile. The closure that you passed to `filter` is missing it’s first parameter, which needs to be either named or discarded with `_`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I think he omitted some of the code inside `filter`

Comment: @aheze yep, but without seeing what the filters are tying to do, it’s hard to recommend an improvement

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica $0.name == text

Comment: Unrelated but why is `searchedText` optional? *not-searching* can be definitely represented by an empty string.

Comment: @vadian because searchText is got from uisearchbar textfield. It can be nil.

Comment: @alphonse You shouldn't be filtering your data set on every lookup of `getFruitByIndex`. That's hugely inefficient. Wrap your `FruitModel` in a `SearchedFruitModel` that filters once, and reused the same filtered result until the search query changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function to prevent duplicate codes for search results

```
func getSearchedFruits() -> [Fruit] {
    if let text = searchedText {
        if !text.isEmpty {
            let searchedFruits = fruits.filter { code }
        }
     return searchedFruits
}
```

And use the result of the getSearchedFruits function to achieve your intend

```
    func getFruit() -> Int {
           getSearchedFruits().count
        }
    }
    
    func getFruitByIndex(_ at: Int) -> Fruit {
         getSearchedFruits()[at]
    }
}
```

Comment: You add and try to run this code in a playground to fix the compilation errors

Comment: @JoakimDanielson my purpose is offer a solution and suitable approach for question.
Of course when i try in pg i will get an error due to compilation errors for example you will get an error as well as both we havent created Fruit object. If you share with me what is wrong basically i would be glad to edit.

Comment: You can create a simple struct Fruit (`struct Fruit { let name: String }`) and add anything for the filter closure that compiles like `{ $0.name == text }` but I am talking about the errors you have introduced. Please fix those as it isn't helpful for future readers if the accepted answer is buggy.

Comment: @alphonse No it doesn't, not the version posted here.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes it does..because it compiled with no errors and works properly. using xcode12, and last version swift

Comment: @alphonse It might do so for you because you have modified it but the code _here_ doesn't compile so don't try to tell me I am wrong when it is so obvious I can just look at the code to see it is incorrect. For starter why don't you count the number of { and }, does the numbers add up?

Answer (score 0):

You can move check for empty `searchedText` into a function.

```
func isTextEmpty(text: String?) -> Bool {
    return text?.isEmpty ?? true /// if text is nil, return true. Otherwise, return `isEmpty`
}
```

Then,

```
func getFruit() -> Int {
    if isTextEmpty(text: searchedText) {
        return fruits.count
    } else {
        let searchedFruits = fruits.filter { code }
        return searchedFruits.count
    }
}
        
func getFruitByIndex(_ at: Int) -> Fruit {
    if isTextEmpty(text: searchedText) {
        return fruits[at]
    } else {
        let searchedFruits = fruits.filter { code }
        return searchedFruits[at]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify to just `text?.isEmpty ?? true`